# C# MySQL executing UPDATE does nothing

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a DataGridView which displays a list of students and their info in a table.
One column named "Grade" is editable so I wish to reflect all changes to the database when the user clicks the "Save Changes" button.

I've wrote this code but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
    private void bttnStudentsSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
            DataTable changes = ((DataView)dataGridViewStudents.DataSource).Table.GetChanges();
            if (changes != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in changes.Rows)
                {
                    MySqlCommand updateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                    updateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE grades
                                            INNER JOIN lectures ON grades.idLecture = lectures.id
                                            INNER JOIN students ON grades.idStudent = students.id
                                            SET grades.grade = '" + row["Grade"] + @"'
                                            WHERE students.id = '" + row["ID"] +
                                                @"' AND (students.name = '" + row["Name"] +
                                                @"' AND students.surname = '" + row["Surname"] +
                                                "') AND lectures.name = '" + row["Lecture"] + "'";
                    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }  
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
```

When this executes there are no changes made to the database.
Since I have to join multiple tables I can't use MySqlCommandBuilder (at least i think that's the reason since I've tried it and got an error about it) so i decided to do it manually.

I've put a couple of breakpoints to check if the data is right and both the `changes` variable and the `CommandText` property contain valid data.

I've tested the MySQL query in SQLyog and it worked there as it should

It's as if the `updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` doesn't execute.

**EDIT:** I've added a few things but it still isn't working. The new code is

```
    private void bttnStudentsSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable changes = ((DataView)dataGridViewStudents.DataSource).Table.GetChanges();
            if (changes != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in changes.Rows)
                {
                    MySqlCommand updateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                    updateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE grades
                                                INNER JOIN lectures ON grades.idLecture = lectures.id
                                                INNER JOIN students ON grades.IDStudent = students.ID
                                                SET grades.grade = @grade
                                                WHERE students.ID = @ID AND (students.name = @name AND students.surname = @surname) 
                                                AND lectures.name = @lecture";
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", row["Grade"]);
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row["ID"]);
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", row["Name"]);
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", row["Surname"]);
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lecture", row["Lecture"]);
                    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }  
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2:** I found out that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns a number of affected rows. I'm getting 0 as a result. Which is odd since the command when executed in SQLyog yields 1 row affected as a result. Weird

**EDIT3:** I found out what the issue is. The database contains Croatian letters (čćšđž) so when they are in a command the command doesn't execute. I think it's something to do with character encoding. When the command only contains regular(ASCII) letters then it works normally. I'm not sure how to fix it yet but at least now i know where the issue lies

**EDIT4:** Issue resolved. Changed the database collation to utf8

Comment: have you confirmed that the sql works outside the program?

Comment: What type is grade. You've potential sql injection attack with this.

Comment: Put a debug on and examine CommandText. Most likely explantion is the where clause is stuffed and there are no matches

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I am aware of sql injecton vulnerability, and I also haven't closed the connection, however I'm just trying to get it to work first. Also i've stated in the OP I've put a breakpoint on the event and checked the values. The sql command is completely valid (I copied it using VS's Text visualizer into SQLyog and it worked in SQLyog). `changes` variable is also filled correctly. So all these things work, yet for some reason it doesn't seem to execute.

Comment: @PreetSangha yes I have. Before adding the code in C# I first tested the code in SQLyog and it executed as it should.

Answer (score 1):

if you have integers in the database type you don't need to give single quotes for the parameters. 
try without singles quotes for number types.

You can avoid all these issues and more safer way is by using parameterized query

**EDIT**

when you get row values you can get it based on type as below

```
row.Field<int>("ID")
```

change your code something like below, check the types again

```
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade",  row.Field<int>("Grade"));
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",  row.Field<int>("ID"));
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  row.Field<string>("Name"));
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname",  row.Field<string>("Surname"));
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lecture",  row.Field<string>("Lecture");
```

Comment: I didn't notice I added single quotes. I removed them but still no dice. I also changed the code up a bit, parameterized the command however it still is not working.

Comment: I don't seem to have `Field` method in my DataRow. Could it be because I'm using Net 2.0? I'm kind of forced to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This code is dangerously fragile. Picking up some connection and not being sure if it is even open is the sign of not really know what's going on.  If you don't even know if you have a connection open then you probably don't know whether it's engaged in a transaction.  I agree with aquaraga - it probably is but you're just so entangled you cannot tell.  There could be another bug elsewhere in the code that doesn't commit.

In any case I'd suggest introducing a design pattern to centralise when you open a connection, create a transaction then do the work then commit or rollback.  Doing it in UI events is a pretty bad practice to say the least.  At least try to separate your UI from your business and data logic.

Comment: The `if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();` statement is useless since it's always closed because I always close it. I have no idea why I wrote it. It's like I didn't trust that `Close()` will actually execute in that finally block(though I should've used using in the first place). Anyway I removed that statement from my code and just left an `connection.Open()` in there and I'm 100% sure that there is nothing else going on when the command is executing. I'm a beginner with C# and MySQL so I'm unaware of good practices regarding them.